# Docker, faz sentido utilizar provisionador?

Tags: docker

Seguinte, tenho feito um estudo mais aprofundado sobre provisionamento de software com ferramentas como o Puppet, Chef e Ansible. Gostaria de saber se faz sentido usar eles com o Docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do lado do host faz sentido. É possível encontrar módulos puppet para gerenciar containers Docker.

Do lado do cliente, não há nada ainda muito definido. Há basicamente duas situações onde o gerenciamento de configuração pode ser utilizado:

- No momento da construção – criação do container
- No momento de inicialização – para finalizar a configuração, aplicando parâmetros específicos de ambiente, antes de inicializar o processo.

Como exemplo, pode-se imaginar um Dockerfile onde o puppet é utilizado, sem o master, para executar algumas configurações do container (momento de construção):

```
# Aqui é considerado que há uma imagem Centos com o Puppet disponível
FROM centos:puppet
ADD conf /etc/puppet/
RUN puppet apply -v -e 'include tomcat7_rhel'
```

Utilizar tal ferramenta no momento de incialização ou até no momento de execução pode ser útil, caso seja necessário executar alguma configuração de ambiente bem complicada.

Ainda se está longe de um consenso sobre o assunto. De qualquer forma, isso implica em dividir as classes / cookbooks para claramente separar em duas execuções, o que é um grande refactoring.

Comment: Ok, muito bem explicado, vejo que para o host é valido a utilização. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você já tem as receitas/módulos prontos, talvez faça sentido sim, mas se ainda for construir, não vejo tanta necessidade.

A ideia do docker é ser o mais simples e declarativo possível, sendo assim fazer o Dockerfile seria o suficiente para suas demandas. Lembre-se que Docker não é uma máquina virtual leve e sim um processo em execução em um ambiente autocontido.